# Why does array concatenation lead to (infinitely?) nested array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, concatenation

If the following code is run in an IRB console:

```
arr = [[], 1]
arr[0]<<arr
```

The result is `[[[...], 1]]`.

Thereafter `arr[0]`, `arr[0][0]`, `arr[0][0][0]`, etc. produce the same output.

This sort of makes sense, because I can't display arbitrary amounts of nesting right?

However, `arr[0][1]` produces nil (rather then `1`) what?
But `arr[0][0][1]` prints `1`.

```
arr[0][0][0][1] => nil
```

then:

```
arr[0][0][0][0][1] => 1
```

etc.

What is going on? What is the structure that is actually created? How deep does this structure recurse? Where are the nils coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see what is inside

```
arr[0]
# => [[[...], 1]]
```

`arr[0]` is an array that has only one element. So `[1]` will be out of this array and return nil.

```
arr[0][0]
# => [[[...]], 1]
```

`arr[0][0]` will get into the only one element of the top array and this element contains two values so `[1]` will found a value.

It behaves so because you did `arr[0] << arr` and not `arr[0] = arr`.
By doing `arr = [[], 1]; arr[0] << arr` you did not set `arr` as `arr[0]` but your added `arr` as an element of arr[0] which is an array itself.

If you had done otherwise

```
arr = ["whatever", 1]
# => ["whatever", 1]
arr[0] = arr
# => [[...], 1]
arr[0][1]
# => 1
arr[0][0][1]
```

**Edit**

Back to your question, why does it become a recursive array. You are not passing `arr`'s value to `arr[0]` but its *reference*.

```
arr = ["whatever", 1]
# => ["whatever", 1]
arr.object_id
# => 69999412942060
arr[0] = arr
# => [[...], 1]
arr[0].object_id
# => 69999412942060
arr[0].object_id == arr.object_id
# => true
```

You have Ouroboros right there since `arr` and `arr[0]` refers the same object.
If you wanted to only insert its value you should have deep_copied it first.

```
arr = ["whatever", 1]
arr_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr)) # copy the value,
                                           # delete the object reference dependence
arr[0] = arr_copy
puts arr.inspect
# [["whatever", 1], 1] # no infinit recurrence.
```

Comment: right brainfart. Actually writing it out does explain the nils and the sizes. However, why doesn't it simply set arr to [[[],1],1]. Why does it recurse at all, and just how deep does it recurse?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I feel like I'm missing something really fundamental.
However, arr = [[],1]
arr[0] << [[],1] Does NOT produce the same, seemingly infinite, nesting, but rather just a single level of nesting. Is it some sort of pass by reference thing that's going on?

Comment: @AbrahamP do you mean you don't see the difference between `<<` and `=` ?

Comment: Modified above comment, accidentally hit enter halfway through, sorry for spam. And yeah I do understand the difference between << and [].
<< pushes a new item onto the tail of an existing array, while = sets the equality of an object to a new object (in this case an array). I also do understand why the length fluctuates. Worth noting however, is that when assigning arr[0] = arr, this "infinite"(for lack of better word) nesting still seems to occur just with a consistent length.

Comment: @AbrahamP when assigning using `=` no matter the length you use, it is always working as exepted, am I wrong ? arr[0]....[0][1] will always return 1 no matter what.

Comment: right, but why does it nest at all? Why doesn't it simply assign itself to:

[[[],1],1] ?

Answer (score 1):

`Array#size` is the essential too to demonstrate why sometimes you are seeing `nil` or `1` as the output:

```
arr = [[], 1]
arr[0]<< arr
arr.size # => 2
arr # => [[[...]], 1]

arr[0] # => [[[...], 1]]
arr[0].size # => 1
arr[0][1] # => nil

arr[0][0] # => [[[...]], 1]
arr[0][0].size # => 2
arr[0][0][1] # => 1

arr[0][0][0] # => [[[...], 1]]
arr[0][0][0].size # => 1
arr[0][0][0][1] # => nil

arr[0][0][0][0] # => [[[...]], 1]
arr[0][0][0][0].size # => 2
arr[0][0][0][0][1] # => 1
```

Comment: right brainfart. Actually writing it out does explain the nils and the sizes. However, why doesn't it simply set arr to [[[],1],1]. Why does it recurse at all, and just how deep does it recurse?